# SQL Server - Return correct column 1 value based on check of column 2 value(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data:

```
| id | Year        | CPT    | RVU   | MOD |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+
| 1  | 2015        | 99212  | 12    | 26  |
| 2  | 2015        | 99212  | 23    | TC  |
| 3  | 2015        | 99212  | 56    |     |
| 4  | 2015        | 99213  | 59    | 53  |
| 5  | 2015        | 99214  | 60    |     |
| 6  | 2015        | 99215  | 99    | 53  |
| 7  | 2015        | 99216  | 78    |     |
```

Output :

Return RVU = 12 for CPT 99212

Return RVU = 59 for CPT 99213

Return RVU = 60 for CPT 99214

Return RVU = 99 for CPT 99215

A CPT can have a MOD of 26, TC, 53, or NULL.  My SQL needs to check for 26 first and if there is a 26 then return the RVU for that row, if not 26 then whatever else is left.

Worded differently: If a CPT does not have a MOD 26, then that CPT will only have one possible other MOD to choose from.  If a CPT has a MOD 26 it will always have an accompanying TC and NULL MOD.  If the CPT does not have a 26 MOD then I need to grab whatever RVU value is available regardless of the MOD.  So the order of operations is to check for 26 first and if there, return RVU for that row, if no 26 then return the only possible RVU choice for that CPT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function with *conditional* ordering :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by cpt 
                                 order by (case when mod = '26' then 0 else 1 end)
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`.  I think the prioritization is as follows:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cpt
                                order by (case mod when '26' then 1 when 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this got me close - im sure with a few edits it would be there

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self-join to get CPTs with a `26` mod in a separate virtual table.

Sample data creation:

```
declare @Data table
(   id int identity
    ,[year] int default 2015
    ,CPT nchar(5)
    ,RVU nchar(2)
    ,[MOD] nchar(2)
)

insert into @Data
(CPT, RVU, [MOD])
values
('99212', '12', '26'),
('99212', '23', 'TC'),
('99212', '56', null),
('99213', '59', '53'),
('99214', '60', null),
('99215', '99', '53'),
('99216', '78', null)
```

Query:

```
select
    Data.CPT
    ,case
        when Is26.CPT is not null then Is26.RVU
        else Data.RVU
    end  RVU
from @Data Data
    left join @Data Is26 on
        Is26.CPT = Data.CPT
        and Is26.[MOD] = '26'
group by
    Data.CPT
    ,case
        when Is26.CPT is not null then Is26.RVU
        else Data.RVU
    end
```

Comment: this is similar to what i had done initially except i did the steps manually.  nice to see it all in one code block.